# Installer generated by wix to update older version doesn't remove folder

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, major-upgrade

I have 2 msi installers generated by WiX. First one (Installer 1) has version = "1.0.0.0", while second (Installer 2) has version = "1.1.0.0". Both of them have ProductCode = "*" and UpgradeCode= "UpgradeCode".

Installer 1 installs an exe file in %AppData%\MyApp\1.0.0.0 folder and also writes an entry in registry under SOFTWARE\MyApp\1.0.0.0. Value of the entry is 1.0.0.0

The expected behavior of Installer 2 is that during its installation previous version (1.0.0.0) will be unistalled from Control Panel, its entry will be deleted from registry, and folder will be unistalled from %AppData%\MyApp.

What really happens is that version 1.0.0.0 is unistalled from Control Panel, entry is deleted from registry and the new version's entry is installed but folder %AppData%\MyApp\1.0.0.0 remains there and a new folder 1.1.0.0 is created under %AppData%\MyApp.

Could anyone help me find what is wrong with my code and how I can solve it?

```
<Product    Id="*" 
            Name="MyApplication" 
            Language="1033" 
            Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" 
            Manufacturer="MyCompany" 
            UpgradeCode="{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}">

    <Package    InstallerVersion="200"
                Compressed="yes" 
                Description="Installer for my application" 
                InstallScope="perUser"/>

    <Upgrade Id="{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}">

        <UpgradeVersion     Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" 
                            OnlyDetect="yes" 
                            Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED"/>

        <UpgradeVersion     Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED"
                            Minimum="1.0.0.0" 
                            IncludeMinimum="yes"
                            Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" 
                            IncludeMaximum="no"/>
    </Upgrade>

    <Property   Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" 
                Value="Disable"/>

    <InstallExecuteSequence>

        <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />

    </InstallExecuteSequence> 

    <Media  Id="1" 
            Cabinet="MyApp.cab" 
            EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Directory  Id="TARGETDIR" 
                Name="SourceDir">

        <Directory  Id="AppDataFolder">

            <Directory      Id="CompanyDir" 
                            Name="MyApp">

                <Component      Id="CompanyDirComp" 
                                Guid="*">

                    <RemoveFolder   Id="RemCompanyDir" 
                                    On="uninstall"
                                    Property="CompanyDir"/>

                    <RegistryValue  Root="HKCU"
                                    Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp"
                                    Name="Uninstall"
                                    Type="string"
                                    Value="$(var.ProductVersion)"
                                    KeyPath="yes"/>

                    <RemoveRegistryKey  Action="removeOnInstall" 
                                        Id="cd"
                                        Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp"
                                        Root="HKCU"/>

                </Component>

                <Directory      Id="INSTALLDIR"
                                Name="$(var.ProductVersion)">

                    <Component  Id="CompanyDirInstallComp"
                                Guid="{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}">

                        <RegistryValue  Root="HKCU"
                                        Key="SOFTWARE\MyApp\$(var.ProductVersion)"
                                        Name="Uninstall"
                                        Type="string"
                                        Value="$(var.ProductVersion)"
                                        KeyPath="yes"/>

                        <RemoveFolder   Id="RemINSTALLDIR" 
                                        On="uninstall"
                                        Property="INSTALLDIR"/>             

                        <File Id="myFile.exe" Source="C:\Users\myFile.exe"/>

                        <RemoveFile     Id="RemMyFile" 
                                        On="uninstall"
                                        Name="*.exe"/>              


                    </Component>

                </Directory>

            </Directory>

        </Directory>

    </Directory>

</Product>
```

Updated question:

I have tested the above code on Windows 8.1x32 and Windows 8.1x64. Installer 2 works as it should on Windows 8.1x64; during its installation previous version (1.0.0.0) is unistalled from Control Panel, its entry is deleted from registry, and folder is unistalled from %AppData%\MyApp. On Windows 8.1x32 installer 2 only unistalls previous version from Control Panel but its entry remains in registry and folder is not deleted.

I ran installer 2 using cmd and the following command:
msiexec /i installer2.msi /l*v log.txt

Windows 8.1x64 output:
Action 2:45:13: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 2:45:13: FindRelatedProducts.
FindRelatedProducts: Found application: {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
MSI (c) (48:7C) [02:45:13:828]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OLDER_VERSION_DETECTED property. Its value is '{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'.
Action ended 2:45:13: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.

Windows 8.1x32 output:
MSI (c) (68:20) [01:45:29:831]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
MSI (c) (68:20) [01:45:29:831]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 1:45:29: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 1:45:29: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 1:45:29: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.

For some reason on Windows 8.1x32 installer 2 cannot find version 1.0.0.0
Any ideas what can cause the issue mentioned above?

Comment: I'd get a verbose log of the upgrade to look for clues. Ideas: If the exe is running out of that folder the timing might not let it be removed, so that extra folder would disappear after a reboot. It might be worth checking that the component guids for those components are different between MSIs so the resources can in fact be removed.

Comment: I got a verbose log but didn't find anything strange. The .exe is not running when I perform the upgrade and folder doesn't disappear after reboot. Replaced the component guid with * but when compiled I got: error CNDL0230 : The Component/@Guid attribute's value '*' is not valid for this component because it does not meet the criteria for having an automatically generated guid. Components with registry keypaths and files cannot use an automatically generated guid. Create multiple components, each with one file and/or one registry value keypath, to use automatically generated guids.